# Webpack cannot import module file when it exists in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, react-on-rails

This only occurs when I am trying to deploy to production both on Heroku and AWS Elastic beanstalk so I know it has to do with my application.

When deploying and failing, the logs read:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/waitlist' in '/var/app/ondeck/app/javascript/waitlist'`

The file tree shows:

```
javascript
  |_home
    |_ components
      |_ App.jsx // import Waitlist from '../../waitlist
  |_waitlist
    |_components
      |_waitlist.jsx
    index.js
```

I know it's reading the `index.js` file because the log reads:

```
@ ./app/javascript/waitlist/index.jsx 1:0-45
@ ./app/javascript/home/components/App.jsx
```

The first line of `waitlist/index.js` reads:

`export { default } from './components/waitlist';`

I've tried importing it as a variable and then exporting it but it does not seem to be able to find the file. I've also tried changing the file extensions between `js` and `jsx` and requiring via an absolute path (`app/javascript/waitlist/components/waitlist`) with no success.

The application works fine using `webpack-dev-sever` on development however. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you build a production bundle locally?